# Scala ClassCastException on Option.orNull

Tags: scala

When I try to run following code:

```
  def config[T](key: String): Option[T] = {
    //in reality this is a map of various instance types as values
    Some("string".asInstanceOf[T])
  }
  config("path").orNull
```

I'm getting error:

> java.lang.String cannot be cast to scala.runtime.Null$
>   java.lang.ClassCastException

Following attempts are working fine:

```
config[String]("path").orNull
config("path").getOrElse("")
```

Since `getOrElse` works its confusing why null is so special and throws an error. Is there a way for `orNull` to work without specifying generic type ?

scalaVersion := "2.12.8"

Comment: The problem is not `orNull` but your `asInstanceOf`. Basically, since you do not specify the _type parameter_ **T**, it infers it from context. In this case it can only infer `Null` given that is the output of `orNull`. And then it tries to do `s.asInstanceOf[Null]`  where **s** is a `String`, that is an error. - `getOrElse` works, because it infers that the output type should be `String`. - As a side note, I hope you are using `orNull` just for interoperability with **Java**, since `null` is not idiomatic in **Scalar**. Second, try to avoid `asInstanceOf` nobody is smarter than the compiler.

Comment: Hi Miguel, thank you for the explanation. I'm using this code for obtaining configuration stored in Map, the values are of various types (String, Int, List, Map, ... - parsed from yaml file), somehow I need to convince the compiler that the type is correct - hence using `asInstanceOf`, what would be a better approach ?

Comment: An **ADT** representing the types of the values, a **typeclass** to get the values in a _type-safe_ way, and implicits to implement that. However, that is probably an _"advanced"_ technique, if you are just starting in **Scala** keep those concepts in mind for a future, I will provide an answer with that in a couple of hours so you can see it. -  For now, you can leave the `asInstanceOf`, however you already see what is the problem with that, it is extremely fragile. You can at least do this `Try(value.asInstanceOf[T]).toOption` to make it more safe.

Comment: @TomasBartalos re. what's a better approach: `config[String]("path")` would be the way to go in your case. You have to indicate to the compiler what type to expect. Something like `val foo: String = config("path").orNull` should work too. Also ... don't use nulls.

Comment: Hi Dima, yep both approaches work fine. Its just so fragile, that it's not a compile-time error and even it works when the value is null. So in my case changing configuration causes unexpected runtime errors.  I need to pass nulls to 3-rd party java lib, otherwise I know nulls are evil ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to show how you may avoid the use `asInstanceOf` to get the values from a typed config.

```
sealed trait Value extends Product with Serializable
final case class IntValue(value: Int) extends Value
final case class StringValue(value: String) extends Value
final case class BooleanValue(value: Boolean) extends Value

type Config = Map[String, Value]

sealed trait ValueExtractor[T] {
  def extract(config: Config)(fieldName: String): Option[T]
}

object ValueExtractor {
  implicit final val IntExtractor: ValueExtractor[Int] =
    new ValueExtractor[Int] {
      override def extract(config: Config)(fieldName: String): Option[Int] =
        config.get(fieldName).collect {
          case IntValue(value) => value
        }
    }

  implicit final val StringExtractor: ValueExtractor[String] =
    new ValueExtractor[String] {
      override def extract(config: Config)(fieldName: String): Option[String] =
        config.get(fieldName).collect {
          case StringValue(value) => value
        }
    }

  implicit final val BooleanExtractor: ValueExtractor[Boolean] =
    new ValueExtractor[Boolean] {
      override def extract(config: Config)(fieldName: String): Option[Boolean] =
        config.get(fieldName).collect {
          case BooleanValue(value) => value
        }
    }
}

implicit class ConfigOps(val config: Config) extends AnyVal {
  def getAs[T](fieldName: String)(default: => T)
              (implicit extractor: ValueExtractor[T]): T =
    extractor.extract(config)(fieldName).getOrElse(default)
}
```

Then, you can use it like this.

```
val config = Map("a" -> IntValue(10), "b" -> StringValue("Hey"), "d" -> BooleanValue(true))

config.getAs[Int](fieldName = "a")(default = 0) // res: Int = 10
config.getAs[Int](fieldName = "b")(default = 0) // res: Int = 0
config.getAs[Boolean](fieldName = "c")(default = false) // res: Boolean = false
```

Now, the problem becomes how to create the typed config from a raw source.
And even better, how to directly map the config to a **case class**.

But, those are more complex, and probably is better to just use something already done, like [**pureconfig**](https://github.com/pureconfig/pureconfig).

---

Just as an academic exercise, lets see if we can support `Lists` & `Maps`.

Lets start with lists, a naive approach would be to have another case class for values which are lists, and create a factory of extractors for every kind of list *(this process is formally know as implicit derivation)*.

```
import scala.reflect.ClassTag

final case class ListValue[T](value: List[T]) extends Value

...

// Note that, it has to be a def, since it is not only one implicit.
// But, rather a factory of implicits.
// Also note that, it needs another implicit parameter to construct the specific implicit.
// In this case, it needs a ClasTag for the inner type of the list to extract.
implicit final def listExtractor[T: ClassTag]: ValueExtractor[List[T]] =
  new ValueExtractor[List[T]] {
    override def extract(config: Config)(fieldName: String): Option[List[T]] =
      config.get(fieldName).collect {
        case ListValue(value) => value.collect {
          // This works as a safe caster, which will remove all value that couldn't been casted.
          case t: T => t
        }
      }
  }
```

Now, you can use it like this.

```
val config = Map("l" ->ListValue(List(1, 2, 3)))

config.getAs[List[Int]](fieldName = "l")(default = List.empty)
// res: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3)
config.getAs[List[String]](fieldName = "l")(default = List("Hey"))
// res: String = List() - The default is not used, since the field is a List...
// whose no element could be casted to String.
```

However, this approach is limited to plain types, if you need a List of other generic type, like a List of Lists. Then, this won't work.

```
val config = Map("l" ->ListValue(List(List(1, 2), List(3))))

val l = config.getAs[List[List[String]]](fieldName = "l")(default = List.empty)
// l: List[List[String]] = List(List(1, 2), List(3)) ???!!!
l.head
// res: List[String] = List(1, 2)
l.head.head
// java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.String
```

The problem here is type erasure, which **ClassTags** can not solve, you may try to use **TypeTags** which can preserve the complete type, but the solution becomes more cumbersome.
For Maps the solution is quite similar, especially if you fix the key type to `String` *(assuming what you really want is a nested config)*. But, this post is too long now, so I would leave it as an exercise for the reader.

---

Nevertheless, as already said, this can be broken easily, and is not completely robust.
There are better approaches, but I myself am not very skilled on those *(yet)*, and even if I would be, the answer would be more long and really not necessary at all.

Lucky for you, even if **pureconfig** does not support **YAML** directly, there is a [module](https://pureconfig.github.io/docs/library-integrations.html) which does, [**pureconfig-yaml**](https://github.com/pureconfig/pureconfig/tree/master/modules/yaml).
I would suggest you to take a look to the module, and if you have further problems ask a new question tagging **pureconfig** and **yaml** directly. Also, if it is just a small doubt, you may try asking in the[**gitter channel**](https://gitter.im/melrief/pureconfig).

Comment: I just see your comment, where you say you need the nulls for a underlying **Java** library. In that case, you can remove the `default` parts from my example and use `orNull` instead.

Comment: Thank you for such an exhaustive answer. I've tried to adopt your example and I'm having problems with generic Collections (List, Map). Obviously I can't name all possible types a Map can have, is there any trick to say this is a ValueExtractor for Map with any generic type (Map[ _, _] doesn't help)? Suggesting a lib is really the best thing to do, however we're using yaml config files and pureconfig doesn't seem to support those (I'm currently using snakeyaml java lib).

Comment: @TomasBartalos I just edited my answer addressing your new question. I hope you will find the last paragraph relieving.

Comment: Thank you Miguel for all your suggestions, maybe I will not use them today and maybe they diverged a bit from the original question, but they're definitely very useful. I will use pureconfig-yaml with a small change - overriding primitives from system properties (useful for docker containers). I already have the code ready and it works very well.